# How to make a control invisible?

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, invisible, wxruby

I've made several TextCtrls and Button, but currently users of my application don't want to see them. So I have to hide them temporary (for current build).
Here they are:

```
class MainFrame < Wx::Frame
    def initialize (parent = nil)
        super nil,:title=>"sometitle",:size=>[600,600]
        set_sizer Wx::BoxSizer.new Wx::VERTICAL

        @tag1 = Wx::TextCtrl.new self
        sizer.add_item @tag1,:flag=>Wx::RIGHT|Wx::EXPAND
        @tag1.set_value 'property'

        @tag1title = Wx::TextCtrl.new self
        sizer.add_item @tag1title,:flag=>Wx::RIGHT|Wx::EXPAND
        @tag1title.set_value 'title'

        @tag2 = Wx::TextCtrl.new self
        sizer.add_item @tag2,:flag=>Wx::RIGHT|Wx::EXPAND
        @tag2.set_value 'description'

        @tag2title = Wx::TextCtrl.new self
        sizer.add_item @tag2title,:flag=>Wx::RIGHT|Wx::EXPAND
        @tag2title.set_value ''

        @button_parse = Wx::Button.new self
        sizer.add_item @button_parse
        @button_parse.label = "Parse XML"
        evt_button @button_parse, :click_parse

        # ......
    end
    # ......
end
```

I see nothing about it in [docs](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl?New_Tutorial) and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=wxruby+OR+wxwidgets+control+invisible) is also not a friend for me today.

Comment: Are they in a sizer? If so, it looks like you could use `Sizer#show` http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/sizer.html#Sizer_show

Comment: @phoffer, yes, it's just want I need! `sizer.show @tag1,false` - You may rewrite comment as answer to make me possible to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are in a sizer, then you'll be able to use [Sizer#show](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/sizer.html#Sizer_show).

```
Boolean show(Sizer sizer,  
         Boolean show = false, 
         Boolean recursive = false)
```

This works for BoxSizer and FlexGridSizer.